# Migrate submission of form from InfusionSoft to Hubspot

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms, hubspot, infusionsoft

I have a form in Orchar CMS, built with a ViewModel, in present times it take the data and submit with InfusionSoft, now, I need to migrate that method of submission to Hubspot, i can't found what I am looking for in the api documentation, but I need to migrate that and I can't find an example of how to do this, any suggestion or link where I can guide myself please!?!?. Here is an example of my form:

```
public class CreateTrialUserHubspotViewModel {

    [StringLength(50), Required, Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50), Required, Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50), Required, Display(Name = "Job title")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "inf_option_countryreport")]
    public bool Country_Reports { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "inf_option_Economicmodel")]
    public bool Economic_Models { get; set; }
```

}

Then I have a controller that take all the data and submit it, here is an example in the method Register of my controller(This is not the full code)

```
[HttpPost, Themed]
    public ActionResult Register(CreateTrialUserViewModel newTrialUser) {    
        //Load Form values in this collection
        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["inf_form_xid"] = infFormXis;
        formData["inf_form_name"] = infFormName;
        formData["infusionsoft_version"] = infVersion;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two strategies to try here:

> **Using an Embeddable HubSpot Form** (Simpler approach)
>
> You can create an embeddable 5-field form that sends data to HubSpot ONLY -- instructions in this user guide: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/forms-user-guide-v2/how-to-create-a-simple-form

---

> **Submitting data from a custom form to HubSpot** (More inline with your current approach)
>
> If you prefer to create the form in C# and Orchard, you can do that too. Create the form the way you would normally for your CMS, than send data to HubSpot using the *Forms API* and *Submit Data* endpoint: http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form

Includes sample C# code. Enjoy!